# Can we write a C++ unit test (don't use a tool) to detect if there is no heap allocation for a piece of code?

Tags: c++, c++14

There is a requirement that the heap allocation of a C++ class is not allowed in the constructor, destructor, and its member functions in a mobile application. Is it possible to test that there is no heap allocation for a piece of code? For example,

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test() {}
    ~Test() {}
    void hasDynamicAllocation1() 
    {
        std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int);
        (void) p;
    }
    void hasDynamicAllocation2()
    {
        std::vector<int> v;
        v.resize(100);
    }
    void noDynamicAllocation()
    {
        member[0] = 1;
    }
private:
    int member[3];
};
```

Unit test:

```
// The following piece of code shall report failure
TEST_F(Foobar, testCase1)
{
    Test t;
    t.hasDynamicAllocation1();
}

// The following piece of code shall report failure
TEST_F(Foobar, testCase2)
{
    Test t;
    t.hasDynamicAllocation2();
}

// The following piece of code shall report pass
TEST_F(Foobar, testCase3)
{
    Test t;
    t.noDynamicAllocation();
}
```

Comment: I suppose you could replace `operator new()` (with a dummy implementation which then raises an alarm)? As a run time check, but that seems to be your use case.

Comment: You would probably need to fake an allocator class and pass it as a template parameter to each of the containers, otherwise I don't think you'll be able to observe whether or not dynamic allocation is occurring.

Comment: A C++ program without heap-allocation... This makes probably half of the standard library useless. (At least, nearly all containers and strings.) I would consider this as a hard requirement. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff, you're right. In real applications, only some specific classes and functions require that. Init and Deinit functions take the roles of allocation/deallocation.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It is OK if only new/delete/malloc/... are used. But there are still some c++ libraries such as vector/string etc that implicitly use the new operator. So it is not an easy task.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I think I catch your idea. I can use a template like `template <typename T> using vector = std::vector<T, allocator<T>>;` to replace the default container, then I could track the memory allocation in allocator.

Comment: Overloading `new` might be enough for your purpose: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/004d2844d8be5a7d)